# How to populate a multidemensional array into an html table using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, html-table

Im working on an assignment where i/m to make an array consisting of 5 of my favorite movies. I'm able to loop through the array to print the names into an html table HOWEVER the second portion of my assignment is in regards to creating a multidimensional array off of the original array that has four sub arrays in regards to 1.the lead actor 2.the lead actors character name 3. the lead actors home town 4. the lead actors age. im then suppose to loop through the multidimensional array to print the data from all the arrays into a 4 column table.

I've pretty new and have been working on this for hours. ive tried having the html table seperate from my  and linking it back together and ive also tried writing the html table within the

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var myMovies = [
['Mr.Nobody', ' Jared Leto', ' Bossier City, LA', ' 47'],
['Jumanji', ' Robin Williams', ' Chicago, IL', ' 63'],
['Hunger Games', ' Jennifer Lawrence', ' Indian Hills, KY', ' 28'],
['Good Will Hunting', ' Matt Damon', ' Cambridge, MA', ' 48'],
['Sucide Squad', ' Margot Robbie', ' Dalby, Australia', ' 28']
        ];


myMovies.unshift(['Crazy Rich Asians', ' Constance Wu', ' Richmond, 
VA', ' 36']);

myMovies.pop();

    document.write('<table>');
    document.write('<tr><th>Movies</th><th>Actors</th><th>Home Towns</th><th>Age</th></tr>');

    for(var i=0, len=myMovies.length; i<len; i++){
        for(var j=0, len2=myMovies[i].length; j<len2; j++){
            document.write('<tr><td' + );
        }
    }

</script>
```

i was able to get the correct results when doing:

```
var myMovies = ['Mr.nobody', ' Jumanji', ' Hunger Games', ' Good 
    Will Hunting', ' Suicide Squad'];

document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>My Movies!</th></tr>');

for var( i=0; i<myMovies.lenght; i++){
    document.write('<tr><td>' + myMovies[i] + '</td></tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: The question has too much bloat to be useful for future readers. Condense the question into a [mcve].

Comment: @Gendarme I don't see how you can say that.  The question seems to me to be about the right size for what Kati's doing.  Look, I won't provide an answer, because I'm not a JavaScript expert, but I think all Kati needs is `document.write('<td>' + myMovies[i][j] + '</td>');` plus some extra lines either side of the inner loop to write the `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem All the information about the size and content of the arrays is irrelevant. The title of the question is perfect, but the question itself is far from minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong. I have fixed it and put it on this snippet bellow.

```js
var myMovies = [
 ['Mr.Nobody', ' Jared Leto', ' Bossier City, LA', ' 47'],
 ['Jumanji', ' Robin Williams', ' Chicago, IL', ' 63'],
 ['Hunger Games', ' Jennifer Lawrence', ' Indian Hills, KY', ' 28'],
 ['Good Will Hunting', ' Matt Damon', ' Cambridge, MA', ' 48'],
 ['Sucide Squad', ' Margot Robbie', ' Dalby, Australia', ' 28']
];

document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>Movies</th><th>Actors</th><th>Home Towns</th><th>Age</th></tr>');

for(var i = 0; i < myMovies.length; i++){
 document.write(`<tr>`);
 for(var j = 0; j < myMovies[i].length; j++){
  document.write(`<td>${myMovies[i][j]}</td>`);
 }
 document.write(`</tr>`);
}
document.write(`</table>`);
```